# Nested observer template

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

I need to observer template with my Notification classes. I use this code:

```
#include <Poco/Notification.h>
#include <Poco/Observer.h>
#include <Util/RegisterObserver.h>
namespace RPC {
class ParseErrorNotify : public Poco::Notification{
public:
    ParseErrorNotify();


private:
    //std::string m_message;
};

template <class C>
class Observer:public Poco::Observer<C,ParseErrorNotify>{
    public:
        typedef Poco::Observer<C,ParseErrorNotify> Base;
        Observer(C& object, Base::Callback method):Base(object,method){}
};

}
```

But I have error while compile:

> ParseErrorNotify.h:20:35: error: 'Poco::Base::Callback' is not a type

I'm using gcc version 4.7.3 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.7.3-1ubuntu1). It's so strange, because with MSVC2010 on win compile ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not strange. You should use `typename`,

```
Observer(C& object, typename Base::Callback method):Base(object,method){}
```

since `Callback` is dependent-name.
Read this [Where and why do I have to put the "template" and "typename" keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) for more information.